# Regex matching multiple spaces/dashes in String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an input that has to be uppercase (with unicode support), and that can contain multiple spaces or dashes `-` (and that should start and end with letters).

I have made this regex : `/^[\p{Lu}]+\s*-*[\p{Lu}]+$/`

As seen [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bi4), this matches everything I need unless it contains multiple dashes or spaces (`ABC DEF` and `ABC-DEF` work, but `AB-CD-EF` and `AB CD EF` don't work).

I am still a beginner with regex so please bear with me :)

Thanks in advance,

Coloco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[\p{Lu}]+(?:\s*-*[\p{Lu}]+)+$

          ^^               ^^
```

Try this.See demo.Make the group accept `1` or more.

https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/7